# Using Angular.js with multiple html select fields, ng-repeat (and ng-model)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, html-select, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to use angularjs with multiple html select fields and I want to store all the selected elements in an array.

May code would look like this:

```
<body ng-app="" ng-controller="myController">
{{selectedElements}}
<div ng-repeat="elem in selectedElements">
    <select 
        ng-model="elem.someThing"   <-- I do not want the someThing here
        ng-options="obj.name for obj in objects">
     </select>

    {{elem}}
</div>
<script>
    var myController = function ($scope) {
        $scope.selectedElements = [{},{}]

        $scope.objects = [
            {"id": "1234","name": "a"}, 
            {"id": "12345","name": "b"},
            {"id": "123456","name": "b"},
            {"id": "123458","name": "c"}
        ];
    };
</script>
```

You can also find a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/dg76hetu/12/

The issue is, that I do not really want to use:

```
ng-model="elem.someThing"
```

because my selectedElements Array then includes "someThing" as a key. (see in fiddle)
Intuitively I would want to do something like:

```
ng-model="elem"
```

However, this does not work and I am also aware that I should not bind to the model without the dot notation.

So my question is, how can I use angular to store all the selected objects from the multiple select fields inside the "selectedElements" Array? I feel like I am missing something basic, however I just can't get it to work.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dg76hetu/13/

Comment: You need a model per each element in selectedElements, otherwise you will be binding both values in the view to the same controller variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can link `ng-model` to actual value using `$index` and passing `array[$index]` in to `ng-model` directly.

Comment: thanks for you quick answer. This actually works great. However, I would also like to have the html select element be initialised if my selectedElements Array would as an example look like so: $scope.selectedElements = [{"id": "1234","name": "a"},{}]. Any idea on how that could be realised with your solution?

Comment: say my array called "$scope.selectedElements" is already initialised with some object(s) instead of those empty objects[{},{}], I would like this to be reflected in the html select field. In other words, the html select field should then already be preselected if the array called "$scope.selectedElements" already contains an element at the beginning. Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z1aujv1x/

Comment: You need to link actual `Object` but not copy of them. To do that create linking function that will run though `selectedElements`, find appropriate actual `Object` in `objects` and link it to origin `selectedElement[i] = objects[j]`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dg76hetu/15/ here is what u want to achieve (with that function that link `Objects`)

Comment: exactly. This is perfect. Thanks a lot :)